# jQuery cookie in magento2 error?

Tags: magento2, cookie

I have this function:

```
jQuery('#sort_order_by').change(function(){ 
        var productUrl = 'product.phtml';
        var value = jQuery(this).val();
        jQuery.cookie('sortorderby', value);            
        var url= productUrl + '?sort_by='+ value;       
        window.location.href = url; 
        jQuery('#sort_order_by').val(jQuery.cookie('sortorderby') || 'helpful' );
    });
```

When executed, `jQuery.cookie('sortorderby')` has value `jQuery('#sort_order_by').val()` not set value of 
`jQuery.cookie('sortorderby')`.

I think that after the location load it does not re-run the code. So I tried create:

```
`function jQuery(function {jQuery('#sort_order_by').val(
    jQuery.cookie('sortorderby') || 'helpful' );});`
```

This gives an error, *jQuery.cookie not function*.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 7):

You need manage dependencies with requirejs:

```
    require([
        'jquery',
        'jquery/jquery.cookie',
         'domReady!'// wait for dom ready
    ], function($) {
        $('#sort_order_by').change(function() { 
            var productUrl = 'product.phtml';
            var value = $(this).val();
            $.cookie('sortorderby', value);            
            var url= productUrl + '?sort_by='+ value;       
            window.location.href = url; 
            $('#sort_order_by').val($.cookie('sortorderby') || 'helpful' );
        }); 
    });
```