# How to create jQuery cookie in cart and show in checkout page on Magento 2?

Tags: magento2, checkout, session, jquery, cookie

I Try to set a Jquery cookie in the cart page with a custom product attibute, and i need to show this attribute on the checkout page.

But i can't find anything how to set and use a cookie.
The only thing i found it's: [jquery cookie](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/93931/jquery-cookie-in-magento2-error), but it's not helping me.
I try to use `jquery.cookie.js` library which is loading in the both page, cart and chekcout!

Can anyone help me with an answer?

Thank you!

Comment: Can you describe in more details what you try achieve? If you need temporary storage for data better use session, not cookies.

Comment: I have a custom product attribute for price for some rent product. in chekcout for this product i want to show the attribute for price, not the 0 price

Comment: you can used magento event observer to pass that value.

Comment: You should ask question how to show custom product attribute in checkout. It should be done by backend developer (in frontend area there will be needed a small changes to .html file: `view/frontend/web/template/summary/item/details.html`)